# Dynamically built criteria applied to form

Tags: sql, vba, dynamic, listbox

I am trying to build a sql statement to apply to a form's recordsource; I'm trying to tailor some code that I found online.  This code is attached to a command button's onclick event. However, the code returns all records associated with the field "Type of Corrective Action" which I attempted to assign to variable "TypeList" (code below).  Can someone please help me figure out why the code return's all values as opposed to filtering for the values chosen in the "type of corrective action" field?

```
Dim filtersql1 As String
Dim qrySql As String
Dim EntriesList As String
Dim TypeList As String
Dim VarItem As Variant


For Each VarItem In Me.lstType.ItemsSelected
    TypeList = TypeList & ",'" & Me.lstType.ItemData(VarItem) & "'"
    Next VarItem

If Len(TypeList) = 0 Then
    TypeList = "Like '*'"

Else
    TypeList = Right(TypeList, Len(TypeList) - 1)
    TypeList = "IN(" & TypeList & ")"

End If



qrySql = "SELECT [Journal Voucher].TAS, [Journal Voucher].Category, [Journal Voucher].[Type of Corrective Action], [Journal Voucher].[VOUCHER#], [Journal Voucher].[Treas-GFMS Variance], " & _
"[Journal Voucher].[JV Reversal Amt], [Journal Voucher].[Original Variance Date], [Journal Voucher].[Corrective Action AP], [Journal Voucher].[Consolidated Log], [Journal Voucher].Offset, " & _
"[Journal Voucher].[AP Added to DB], [Journal Voucher].[Date Added to DB], [Journal Voucher].[Ready to Submit], [Journal Voucher].[Date Submitted], [Journal Voucher].[Date of Reversal JV], " & _
"[Journal Voucher].[Fiscal Year] FROM [Journal Voucher] "

filtersql1 = "WHERE [Journal Voucher].TAS= '" & Me.lstEntries.Value & "' AND [Journal Voucher].[Type of Corrective Action] & TypeList;"
qrySql = qrySql & filtersql1

Debug.Print qrySql

DoCmd.OpenForm "Journal Voucher", acFormDS
Forms![Journal Voucher].RecordSource = qrySql

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `filtersql1` isn't formatted correctly, with TypeList being inside the "s rather than outside.  I think it should look something like this:

```
filtersql1 = "WHERE [Journal Voucher].TAS= '" & Me.lstEntries.Value & "' AND [Journal Voucher].[Type of Corrective Action] " & TypeList & ";"
```

Comment: Ian, thank you so much.  Sorry about the delayed response-- I've been away.